# php large object/array loop performance

Tags: php, performance

I'm currently attempting to find a solution to my current problem.

Giving the following code:

```
$array = array();
for($a=0;$a!=1000;$a++) {
    $std = new \stdClass();
    $array[] = $std;
    $count = count($array);
    for($i=0;$i!=$count;$i++);
}
```

PHP will run the script in around 0.052025079727173 seconds

Giving:

```
$array = array();
for($a=0;$a!=100000;$a++) {
    $std = new \stdClass();
    $array[] = $std;
    $count = count($array);
    for($i=0;$i!=$count;$i++);
}
```

Takes around 3.0082960128784 seconds.

Given:

```
$array = array();
for($a=0;$a!=100000;$a++) {
    $std = new \stdClass();
    $array[] = $std;
    $count = count($array);
    //for($i=0;$i!=$count;$i++);
}
```

Runs at 0.3171501159668.

Now I do understand that I am looping at high rates and I haven't ventured to much into this area.

So my question is this simply wrong and it should be handled differently, does PHP not handle transversing large data sets very well or is looping very large amounts of data simply not a wise idea in any language.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? What's the problem? All I see is that when you loop more times, it takes longer. That should be obvious, but what's the issue?

Comment: Not really an answer, but what are you trying to do ? In your example you are not traversing data, just incrementing an integer and checking its value with another, it would be worth pointing out what your goal is so that we can give you a better way to achieve it (if any). In your "slow" example, you are looping 100000 * 100000 times and doing both comparison and incrementing for every iteration.

Comment: my issue is the amount of time taken to perform these loops

Comment: This question seems like "I have done this, show me what can you do...."

Comment: i just dont understand why are you instantiating i million objects in a loop and i am sure soon you will get time out or memory exceptions for killing the server , or may be they charging too much hosting fee.:) but what exactly is the question here?

Comment: nwhiting: what are you trying to do with these loops ? What is a given task you need to perform ? To answer your question, no, doing 10 billions operations is not fast and recommended if there is a shorter way. So tell us what you want to do so we can give you a shorter way.

Comment: You have tested this with such data, i give you a suggestion, loop only 2 values, try to `sleep(10000)` in between, it will be more delayed. :P

Comment: I fail to understand the purpose of your query. More intense the program, more time the script will take to complete.

PHP handles large data-sets very well; ummm just like rockets handle large loads of satellites. But just like rockets will crash if they carry load more than they are designed to, so will downfall the performance of any programming language if it's doing a complex or a loaded task. How complex depends on how suited the language is for the purpose & how nice the environment is in which it's running

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This issue has been well addressed and is formally known in computer science circles as "big  O" notation.  Here is a [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) to an article describing Big-O notation.   At this point your Big-O value is exponential due to the nested/embedded loop inside of that larger loop.

I should note that what you are doing is not wrong, and PHP is equipped to be able to process large amounts of data, however as Coding Freak pointed out, you may run out of memory.  I don't know the context of what you are trying to do, but perhaps consider doing your operations on a "as needed" basis, this will improve your performance a little as you wouldn't be initializing/setting/modifying the entire block of data, unless of course you are trying to perform some sort of large batch operation (I'm thinking of page load time here, and if you are doing a large batch op that only happens once a day, there is much less to worry about).

You may want to consider a different way to handle your computation, although since you have not really posted an objective you would like to achieve I'm rather limited in being able to offer solutions.

This is a very minor side comment, but when you are doing for loops, don't make the check "i != 1000" do "i < 1000" this way if for some reason your increment variable jumps over 1000 you will not end up with an infinite loop.  Like I said, a very minor comment -- in the context of your code, it is not necessary, but also not the best of practices as it can lead to bugs.

Regards,

H

Comment: "At this point your Big-O value is exponential"  It looks quadratic to me.

Answer (score 2):

> So my question is this simply wrong and it should be handled differently, does PHP not handle transversing large data sets very well or is looping very large amounts of data simply not a wise idea in any language.

Well performance wise PHP is not as fast as let's say C code or assembler. But that leads to nothing.

So doing many iterations always takes time. In any language. You have many of them so this takes it's time. So don't do loops just for fun but to actually accomplish something ;).

Comment: So don't do loops just for fun , i like it giving u one

Answer (score 0):

This line is unnecessary:

```
$count = count($array);
```

You should know what the array count is, you don't have to re-count this every time round the loop.  Try replacing this and see if the performance scales better.

HTH.

Comment: The `count()` function is O(1), at least if [what this person says](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.count.php#101882) is true.